# Sorting multidimensional array C++ strange behaviour

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm doing some programming practice right now by trying to sort a 2D array on it's first "column".

I am reading input from a file:

```
100 5
8 80
5 20
9 40
3 10
6 30
```

This is my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool helper(vector<long> k, vector<long> l)
{
   return (k[0] < l[0]);
}

int main()
{
   ifstream fi("milk.in");
   ofstream fo("milk.out");
   long price = 0, n, m, i, p, a;
   vector< vector<long> > farmers;
   vector<long> farmer(2,0);
   fi >> n >> m;

   for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
   {
      fi >> p >> a;
      farmer[0] = p;
      farmer[1] = a;
      farmers.push_back(farmer);
   }


   sort(farmers.begin(),farmers.end(),helper);


   for (i=0; i<m; ++i)
   {
      cout << farmers[i][0] << " " << farmers[i][1] << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I try to sort the input by it's first column (I don't care about the first line at the moment).

However, this is the result:

```
3 10
5 20
6 30
6 30
6 30
```

This is the expected result:

```
3 10
5 20
6 30
8 80
9 40
```

I can't figure it out.

Comment: did you try changing first line of file?

Comment: An unrelated performance problem: You are passing the vectors to the comparison function by value. I would suggest passing by const reference instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first line of your `milk.in`:

```
100 5
```

You're going to end up looping through trying to read in 100 inputs from this file because n = 100.

```
fi >> n >> m;
for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
```

If you change milk.in to:

```
5 5
8 80
5 20
9 40
3 10
6 30
```

That seems to work.

Perhaps a better idea is to just check if you're done reading input from the filestream:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if(!(fi >> farmer[0] >> farmer[1])) break;

    farmers.push_back(farmer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this loop to load  the data from the file in:
And remember to close the file.

```
   while(!fi.eof()) 
   {
     fi >> n >> m;
    farmer[0] = n;
    farmer[1] = m;
    farmers.push_back(farmer);
   }

   fi.close( );
```

Also, I made some minor changes to your code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool helper(vector<long> k, vector<long> l)
{
   return (k[0] < l[0]);
}

int main()
{


   long price = 0, n, m, i, p=0, a=0,numlines=0;
   vector< vector<long> > farmers;
   vector<long> farmer(2,0);

   cout<<"\nLoading data from file: milk.in\n\n";

   ifstream fi("milk.in");
   while(!fi.eof()) 
   {
     fi >> n >> m;
     numlines++;
     cout<<n<<" "<<m<<"\n";

    farmer[0] = n;
    farmer[1] = m;
    farmers.push_back(farmer);
   }

   fi.close( );


   cout<<"--- "<<numlines<<" lines loaded\n";
   cout<<"\n---------------------\n";

   cout<<"\nSorted data:\n\n";

   sort(farmers.begin(),farmers.end(),helper);

   ofstream fo("milk.out");
   for (i=0; i<numlines; ++i)
   {

      cout << farmers[i][0] << " " << farmers[i][1] << endl;
      fo<< farmers[i][0] << " " << farmers[i][1] << endl;

   }
   fo.close();

   cout<<"\n---------------------\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Sorted data:

3 10
5 20
6 30
8 80
9 40
100 5
```